# What IDE can support Java-to-JavaScript along with Angular?

Tags: angular, ide, jsweet

I'm trying to start a project that'll use Angular to build a web application and re-use/extend my existing (generic) Java code by automatically transpiling it into JavaScript when changes or additions are made.

JSweet seems like it'll be the best for what I want but I'm not absolutely set on that.

However, I haven't been able to get an IDE to work...

- I have a trial version of IntelliJ Ultimate.  It supports Angular but not JSweet.
- I have Eclipse 4.26.  It supports JSweet via plugin but the Angular plugin is EOL.
- I'm looking at VSCode.  It looks to support Angular but I can find nothing about JSweet.

*Is there a working solution for this somewhere?*

Answer (score 0):

After several days of trying different things, I gave up on the path stated in the question.  My solution:

- Use Angular/CLI to build the project and sub-projects.
- Import into IntelliJ.
- Convert Java classes to Kotlin classes (IntelliJ does most of this)
- Use Kotlin/JS to build Javascript/Typescript library from it.
- Import said lib into Angular.